# how to use state machine that invalidate value like "0.10"

Tags: state-machine

[image: state machine]

Above is the state machine I copied from 
http://discuss.leetcode.com/questions/241/valid-number

I think it cannot invalid values like "0.10".
It is possible to create a state machine that can invalidate values does not ends of "0"?

Comment: I do not fully understand the connection between the diagram and the question. Do you mean to say that the state machine does accept the input "0.10"?

Comment: There is nothing "invalid" in `0.10`. Why do you want to invalidate it ?

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing from your single example, I assume that you want to refuse that the fractional part ends in `0`.

The place to do that is around state `4`, which is where the digits of the fractional part are processed, and can be ended by `e/E` or a `space`.

You will need to distinguish the `0` from other digits, and duplicate this state: `4` for `nonzero digits`, `4°` for `0`. Also duplicate/adapt the incoming transitions (`1->4`, `2->4` and `4->4`). Rejection will be achieved by omitting `4°->5` and `4°->8` and not letting `4°` be an accepting state.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible. To disallow a trailing zero completely, a straightforward approach would be to duplicate each terminal node into two: the one reachable with digits `1` to `9` and the one reachable with `0`. After that, adjust the transitions accordingly.

On the other hand, by the nature of your question, it looks like you will also want to disallow numbers such as `0.` and maybe others. What exactly is allowed would require a rigorous definition, and while messing with the existing state machine is certainly possible, it may turn out your rules are actually simpler than the ones used in it. And in that case, you will be better off just constructing a new state machine from scratch according to your definition.

Comment: I think the best way to avoid trailing 0, is the to make digit loop into a loop between 2 digit states, where inputting 0 will lead to a state that only accept [1-9] digits which takes it back the first one